# Transposing an array based on meeting conditions

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

I have a set of values, narrations,and date of the transaction. the value and transaction might bee recurring. I need to list the value and narration in another sheet   and recurring date in the cells next to it.

Eg:

```
Date        Narration   Value 
01/01/2016  Ramu        $500
02/01/2016  John        $1000
03/01/2016  Sumil       $300
04/02/2016  Ramu        $500
05/02/2016  John        $1000
06/02/2016  Sumil       $300
01/03/2016  Ramu        $500
```

**I need the set off values to be listed in another cell in this manner**

```
Narration      Value     Date
Ramu           $500      01/01/2016- 04/02/2016- 01/03/2016
Sumil          $300      03/01/2016- 06/02/2016
John           $1000     02/01/2016 -05/02/2016
```

Comment: I have the above data in excel and i have used countif formula to identify the recurring values and have copied the same to another sheet. Then i have to list the values as mentioned above.

Comment: Can the dates in the output table be in separate cells? Or do you need all dates in a single cell?

Comment: it has to be in separate cells.

Comment: You can do this with formula to, do you have any code to show?

Comment: Im a beginner and have no idea to do that.

Comment: @LakshmikanthSundararajan Unfortunately, this site does not accommodate code requests. You will need to make an attempt on what you are asking and display your code in order to receive assistance. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you need a pivot table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Formula method**

In the example below.

In F1 I have `=B2`, in F2 down, I have the array formula `=INDEX($B$2:$B$13,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$2:F2,$B$2:$B$13),0),1)`

In G2:N13, I have the array formula `=INDEX($A$2:$A$13,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$13=$F2,ROW($B$2:$B$13)-1),COLUMNS($G$1:G$1)),1)`

Hope this helps, you can add some error controlling like `iserror` to clean it up

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nathan_Sav for your Inputs. I would like to do it as a macro. B'coz i have lot of such things to be done. Can you help me on that?

Comment: What should I DO if i need to compare "values" as well. In the above formula  compares just the "narration". Eg in case Person 1 has the value of   200 then a separate entity has to be shown.